# Updating Active Directory via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hallo I got a question with my update script for my active directory
I am trying to update a user using .csv document
It’s for my understanding very simple but there is an error which I cant find out why it occurs.

My Script:

```
#Get CSV content
 $CSVrecords = Import-Csv "C:\scripts\test.csv" -Delimiter ";"
    
 #Create arrays for skipped and failed users
 $SkippedUsers = @()
 $FailedUsers = @()
    
 #Loop trough CSV records
 foreach ($CSVrecord in $CSVrecords) {
         $upn = $CSVrecord.UserPrincipalName
         $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$upn'"
         if ($user) {
                 try {
                         $user | Set-ADUser -Department $CSVrecord.Department -Company $CSVrecord.Company -ErrorAction STOP
                 }
                 catch {
                         $FailedUsers += $upn
                         Write-Warning "$upn user found, but FAILED to update."
                 }
         }
         else {
                 Write-Warning "$upn not found, skipped"
                 $SkippedUsers += $upn
         }
}
```

The Date that I am trying to use for the Update:

| UserPrincipalName | Department | Company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test.nikola@test.local | Test | 123 |

The Error message that I get: user found, but FAILED to update

Maybe I am blind but i cant find the error ...

Comment: The `try{}catch{}` blocks are _hiding_ the real error. Change the warning to `Write-Warning "Update failed: $_"` to see the actual underlying error. (`$_` refers to the triggering exception inside the `catch` block)

Comment: Your `catch` block is preventing us to see the real error, comment the `Write-Warning` line and add `$_.Exception.Message` to your catch block

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Insufficient permission!!! OMFG Thank so much you can post it as an answer if you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your `catch` block is hiding *all* terminating exceptions. Since you never output or inspect the given exception, there's no way to tell what went wrong.

Change it to:

```
try {
    $user | Set-ADUser -Department $CSVrecord.Department -Company $CSVrecord.Company -ErrorAction STOP
}
catch {
   $FailedUsers += $upn
   Write-Warning "$upn user found, but FAILED to update: $_"
}
```

Inside the catch block, `$_` will refer to the exception that was caught, so at least you now get a chance to see the underlying error message.